# Split columns out of MySQL table using Liquibase

Tags: mysql, grails, data-migration, liquibase

I have an existing table with data in it.

```
foobar_table
    foo
    bar
    baz
```

I want to split the `baz` column out of the `foobar_table` table and create a new table called `baz_table` that contains it.  After the operation is done I would have the following structure with each column containing the data it had before the operation started:

```
foobar_table
    foo
    bar

baz_table
    baz
```

How can I do this with [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/)?

P.S. Using Liquibase via the [Grails Database Migration plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/database-migration).  The [grailsChange](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-database-migration/docs/manual/guide/5%20Groovy%20Changes.html) tag gives me hope, but lack of example documentation leave me wanting.

**Update:**

I wasn't aware of the `sql` that can be used in change sets.  I found out about it in the example [here](http://assarconsulting.blogspot.com/2011/08/database-migration-in-grails.html) and I think it is what I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already found out, you can run arbitary SQL queries as a part of changeset. I go over common caveats in my [blog post](http://scalabilitycookbook.com/2012/10/05/control-your-database-schema/).

So for your example:

```
<changeset>
  <createTable tableName="baz_table"/>
  <sql>insert into baz_table(baz) select baz from foobar</sql>
  <dropColumn tableName="foobar_table" columName="baz"/>
</changeset>
```